# How to take a screenshot and display it in a window (without saving the file)?

Tags: python

All tutorials I found on the internet guided me to take a screenshot with some module and then save it.
Non of them show how to take some data and build from it an image...

This what I basically trying to do:

```
import pyscreenshot

# get a screenshot image.
img = pyscreenshot.grab()

# convert img data to bytes
img_data = ???

# build new img from img_data
new_img = ???

#display the image...
```

(If you can please provide small script of python)

Comment: Are you not able to use the [`show`](https://pyscreenshot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#examples) method are described in documentation?

Comment: Have you tried simply ```using plt.imshow(new_img)``` with ```import matplotlib.pyplot as plt```?

Comment: The hard part is that I need to convert the image to some data and only then build the new img

Comment: @DanielBartov What does that mean? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
import io
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
img = ImageGrab.grab()
buffer = io.BytesIO()
img.save(buffer, format="jpeg_or_png_or_whatever")
img_data = buffer.getvalue()
temp_filepath = "something.png"
with open(temp_filepath, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img_data)
img.show()
```

Here `img` is an image object read by pillow and just doing `img.show()` would pop up a window showing the whole screenshot. You need to create a buffer with help of `BytesIO` for saving the image as bytes and using it later.

In the above process reconstructing a pillow image Object from bytes format created by `BytesIO` might create a problem. `Image.frombytes()` gave me some error for me, tbh.

But, we can use the inbuilt method `.tobytes()` in stead of creating a buffer and putting data into it. Pillow can easily later create an image object from that bytes object later. The only downside of the following process might be that you will need the mode and size of the originally grabbed screenshot image object of which we created a bytes format. Try this :

```
import io
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from PIL import Image
img = ImageGrab.grab()
img_data = img.tobytes()
recons_img = Image.frombytes(img.mode, img.size, img_data)
img.show()

#recons_img.save('something.png') #If you want to save later
```

Comment: After I have the img_data, how do I build an image object with it? (I need to display the img_data not img)

Comment: Thanks a lot but is there any way to do it without saving? (Sorry for bothering)